# Text is not being aligned flexbox react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I am new using flexbox and react native. I am trying to do something very simple and center the text. However it doesn't seem to be working. Below is the code I am using. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
<View style={{"display": "flex","align-items": "center","justify-content":"center"}}>
         <Text> {selected_order_date} {selected_order_time} </Text>

     </View>
```

Comment: Try this: style={{display: 'flex', align-items: 'center', justify-content:'center'}}

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{"flexDirection": "row","alignItems": "center","justifyContent":"center"}}>
         <Text> {selected_order_date} {selected_order_time} </Text>

     </View>
```